# Google Maps not displaying clearly in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

1. My app in Android Studio does not load the locations (map) clearly, it viewed parts of the world but shows the blue only.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

2. I can't view the textviews and buttons I dragged in the layout design view.

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

**app (gradle)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stylers.maps"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Dataparser (underjavafolder)**

```
package com.example.stylers.maps;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DataParser {
    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject googlePlaceJson){
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlaceMap = new HashMap<>();
        String placeName = "-NA-";
        String vicinity = "-NA-";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String reference = "";
        try {
        if (!googlePlaceJson.isNull("name")){

                placeName = googlePlaceJson.getString("name");

        }
        if(!googlePlaceJson.isNull("vicinity")){
            vicinity = googlePlaceJson.getString("vicinity");
        }
        latitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = googlePlaceJson.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");

        reference = googlePlaceJson.getString("reference");

        googlePlaceMap.put("place name",placeName);
        googlePlaceMap.put("vicinity",vicinity);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lat",latitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("lng",longitude);
        googlePlaceMap.put("reference",reference);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlaceMap;
    }
    private List<HashMap<String,String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jsonArray){
        int count = jsonArray.length();
        List<HashMap<String,String>> placesList = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> placeMap = null;

        for(int i= 0; i<count; i++){
            try {
                placeMap = getPlace((JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i));
                placesList.add(placeMap);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesList;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(String jsonData){
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return getPlaces(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

**DownloadUrl (underjavafolder)**

```
package com.example.stylers.maps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class DownloadUrl {

    public String readUrl(String myUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myUrl);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data= sb.toString();
            br.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            inputStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

**GetNearbyPlaces (underjavafolder)**

```
package com.example.stylers.maps;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class GetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    String googlePlacesData;
    GoogleMap mMap;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        mMap = (GoogleMap)objects[0];
        url = (String)objects[1];

        DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
        try {
            googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return googlePlacesData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
       List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList = null;
       DataParser parser = new DataParser();
       nearbyPlaceList = parser.parse(s);
       showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList);
    }

    private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList){
        for(int i =0; i<nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++){
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);

            String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
            String vicinity = googlePlace.get("vicinity");
            double lat= Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get("lng"));

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title(placeName+" : "+vicinity);
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stylers.maps">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MapsActivity.java (underjavafolder)**

```
package com.example.stylers.maps;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private Location lastLocation;
    private Marker currentLocationMarker;
    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE = 99;
    int PROXIMITY_RADIUS=10000;
    double latitude,longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       switch(requestCode)
       {
           case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
               if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               {
                   //permission is granted
                   if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                       if(client == null){
                           buildGoogleApiClient();
                       }
                       mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                   }
               }
               else{
                   Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               return;
       }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }



    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        client.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       lastLocation = location;

       if(currentLocationMarker != null){
           currentLocationMarker.remove();
       }

       LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
       markerOptions.position(latLng);
       markerOptions.title("Current Location");
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));

       currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

       if(client != null)
       {
           LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client, this);
       }
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.B_search: {
            EditText tf_location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TF_location);
            String location = tf_location.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = null;
            MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();


            if (!location.equals("")) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 5);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {
                    Address myAddress = addressList.get(i);
                    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(myAddress.getLatitude(), myAddress.getLongitude());
                    mo.position(latlng);
                    mo.title("Your search result");
                    mMap.addMarker(mo);
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                }

            }
        }
        break;
            case R.id.B_pharmacy:
                mMap.clear();
                String pharmacy = "pharmacy";
                String url = getUrl(latitude,longitude,pharmacy);
                Object dataTransfer[] = new Object[2];
                dataTransfer[0]= mMap;
                dataTransfer[1]=url;

                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(dataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Showing nearby pharmacy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
    }
    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace){
        StringBuilder googlePlaceUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/");
        googlePlaceUrl.append("location"+latitude+","+longitude);
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&radius="+PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&type="+nearbyPlace);
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlaceUrl.append("&key="+"AIzaSyA9cANY3r4v26Sz9dPbLlvuv_1WP19vI7w");

        return googlePlaceUrl.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();

    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);


    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client,locationRequest,this);
    }
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
         if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
         }
         else
         {
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
         }
         return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

**Activity_maps.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="470dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TF_location"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/B_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Search"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B_pharmacy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="Pharmacy"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 1st problem is in the "2" link photo

Comment: 1st problem, should I post the code? :) , anyone help? :)

Comment: yes, post the code

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes done bro

Answer (score 0):

In OnMapReady you could center the map in the user not just on the onLocationChanged() so that will prevent you to see that blue screen while your location didn't change

Could you try to to something like below on your onMapReady

```
   @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

       mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

      // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
      if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
        new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
      }

}
```